# Create new entity in broadleaf

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, broadleaf-commerce

**Note** : I am using PostgreSQL database
    After the build and run **table is not created** in database
    I do same as broadleaf documentation for create new entity:

```
   1.  **Created new interface** :

package com.mycompany.entity.ordereturn;

 public interface OrderReturn {
        Long getId();
        void setId(Long id);
        String getReason();
        void setReason(String reason);
        String getAddress();
        void setAddress(String address);
    }
```

2. **Created new OrderReturnImpl class** :

   @Entity

   @Table(name = "blc_order_return")

   ```
   public class OrderReturnImpl implements OrderReturn{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator= "OrderReturnId")
   @GenericGenerator(
           name="OrderReturnId",
                       strategy="org.broadleafcommerce.common.persistence.IdOverrideTableGenerator",
           parameters = {
               @Parameter(name="segment_value", value="OrderReturnImpl"),
               @Parameter(name="entity_name", value="com.mycompany.entity.ordereturn.OrderReturnImpl")
           }
       )    

   @Column(name = "OrderReturn_ID")
   protected Long id;

   @Column(name = "Reason")
   protected String reason;

   @Column(name = "Address")
   protected String address;

   @Override
   public Long getId() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return id;
   }

   @Override
   public void setId(Long id) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       this.id = id;
   }

   @Override
   public String getReason() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return reason;
   }

   @Override
   public void setReason(String reason) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       this.reason = reason;
   }

   @Override
   public String getAddress() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return address;
   }

   @Override
   public void setAddress(String address) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       this.address = address;
   }
   }
   ```

   3. **Configure in persistence-core.xml file** :

   > ```
   >  <persistence-unit name="blPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   >         // Added this line in name = "blPU"
   >             <class>com.mycompany.controller.account.OrderReturnImpl</class>
   >              <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
   >         </persistence-unit>
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

Although you havent posted your full `OrderReturnImpl.java` file, you're probably missing the `@Entity` annotation (along with `@Table` annotation).

Please annotate your class accordingly.

OK i see a new edit and you now have the annotations. So the error still continues **with** these annotations?

if you want to create the database tables from the entities, please use
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Comment: @BhaumikSathvara so the class is actually at this package, right? `com.mycompany.controller.account`. also please post the full stacktrace. it will be more helpful to see if sth else happens before that.

Comment: But when i follow this: http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/core-tutorials/creating-a-new-entity then i am not getting any error and also not create any table in database.

Comment: have you tried with `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`? you want to create the database table from the entity right?

Comment: yes i already did it. and also yes i want to create the database table from this entity.

Comment: ok so please include the full stacktrace then in your question. thnx

Comment: But i not have a any exception.

Comment: so what about `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.mycompany.entity.ordereturn.OrderReturnImpl`?

Comment: Its not in our case that's why I have removed it from my question.

Comment: I am just following documentation I have shared with you, restarting broadleaf  admin and site. According to documentation table should be created in DB. but its not happening in our case.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is with creating tables if you are running admin/site on standalone server. Try it on embedded tomcat or jetty.

configure:

- In admin/resource/runtime-properties/development.properties

```java
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
blCMSStorage.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
blSecurePU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

- In core/resource/runtime-properties/common-shared.properties

```java
blPU.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
blSecurePU.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
blCMSStorage.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.broadleafcommerce.common.util.sql.importsql.DemoPostgresSingleLineSqlCommandExtractor
blSecurePU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.broadleafcommerce.common.util.sql.importsql.DemoPostgresSingleLineSqlCommandExtractor
blCMSStorage.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.broadleafcommerce.common.util.sql.importsql.DemoPostgresSingleLineSqlCommandExtractor
```

- database.properties populated with your data

Be sure to have:

- PostgreSQL driver in [standaloneserver]/lib or as a library if you run on embedded servers
- Invalidated IDE cache
- Clean and install maven goals on all project (or on all three modules)
- postgresql start database in pom's executions and postgresql dependency

```xml
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.8</version>
          <executions>
               <execution>
                    <id>postgres-start</id>
                    <configuration>
                         <target>
                              <echo message="Starting postgres database..."/>
                              <java fork="true" spawn="true" classname="org.postgresql.Driver"
                                      classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath">
                              </java>
                              <echo message="Database started successfully"/>
                         </target>
                     </configuration>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>run</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
              <dependencies>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                      <version>9.4.1211</version>
                  </dependency>
              </dependencies>
```